# How to store two dimensional array with sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a problem. I need to store 2d array with sqlite3. How is it possible. I know that 1d array could be converted into string and stored like that, but with 2d array it would be quite complicated. I am taking data from excel and using them in matplotlib.

```
[['', 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 12.0, 14.0], ['IB=4', 0.143, 0.146, 0.152, 0.158, 0.167], ['IB=8', 0.415, 0.425, 0.43, 0.44, 0.45], ['IB=10', 0.545, 0.555, 0.57, 0.58, 0.59], ['IB=12', 0.766, 0.778, 0.79, 0.81, 0.83]]
```

Comment: So your data is always the same? The rows (inner list) have always the same size? In that case you could save each inner list as a row in sqlite

Comment: You could dump the list to JSON, and store that

Comment: What do you need to do with the data? Do you need to query it too, or just store it for retrieval as a full blob?

Comment: SQL doesn't work in terms of arrays. What does this data represent? Is it always the same six values? Are the values in order?

Comment: @Schwern the 0th array represents voltage and the rest are values of current in transistor. The size does not change. Basically this 2d array consists of rows taken form excel table.

Comment: @DaniMesejo yes the size is always the same.

Comment: @AKX I just need to store it, later retrieve it. After retrieving it i would just process the retrieved data.

Comment: If you just need to save and load the array do you need SQLite? Consider converting it to JSON and saving it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example that saves arbitrary Python objects (by [`pickle`ing](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) them) into two-column tables in SQLite databases.

If you have a more complex use case, you can probably adapt this.

```
import sqlite3
import pickle

DEFAULT_TABLE = "arrays"


def save_blob(db, name, data, table_name=DEFAULT_TABLE):
    pickled_data = pickle.dumps(data, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    db.execute(
        f"INSERT INTO {table_name} (name, data) VALUES (?, ?) ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET data=data",
        (name, pickled_data),
    )


def load_blob(db, name, table_name=DEFAULT_TABLE):
    res = db.execute(f"SELECT data FROM {table_name} WHERE name = ?", (name,))
    row = res.fetchone()
    if not row:
        raise KeyError(name)
    return pickle.loads(row[0])


def create_blob_table(db, table_name=DEFAULT_TABLE):
    db.execute(
        f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} (name TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, data BINARY NOT NULL)"
    )


def main():
    data = [
        ["", 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 12.0, 14.0],
        ["IB=4", 0.143, 0.146, 0.152, 0.158, 0.167],
        ["IB=8", 0.415, 0.425, 0.43, 0.44, 0.45],
        ["IB=10", 0.545, 0.555, 0.57, 0.58, 0.59],
        ["IB=12", 0.766, 0.778, 0.79, 0.81, 0.83],
    ]

    db = sqlite3.connect("./db.sqlite3")
    create_blob_table(db, DEFAULT_TABLE)
    save_blob(db, "thing1", data)
    db.commit()  # Remember to commit changes after saving things.
    data2 = load_blob(db, "thing1")
    print(data == data2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```